# which viewcontroller is showing inside ContainerView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xcode5, uicontainerview

How do I find out which UIViewController is presently showing inside my UIContainerView?

I already have an IBOutlet of my UIContainerView called `self.containerView`. [Everything is working fine](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html). I just need to be able to know which VC is currently showing.

**SNIPPET FROM APPLE (there is a bit more in link)**

```
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
   [self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController]; // 2
   [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
}
```

Here `content` of course is a reference to the VC in question.

Comment: Are you adding them to a scrollview inside the container view? Need more setup context

Comment: No scroll view, just the basic Apple instructions that I linked to. I will edit to show the same snippet from Apple that I am using

Comment: So why aren't you just keeping a reference to that content viewController?

Comment: That's a good observation. But it would be a dangerous way of doing it due to the multiple methods involved in swapping the contents of the UIContainerView. I am hoping someone here might have a more sound design pattern.